# Why can't I shutdown the Netty Server or Netty Client ？

Tags: netty

#### Expected behavior

I have launched a netty server and establish a connection with it via netty client. The client sends a message to the server, while the server will feedback and close context (Channel), when the client got a message from the server, it will close channel and shutdown EventLoopGroup, and then exit the program.

#### Actual behavior

However, all the channel was closed, but the EventLoopGroup unable to shutdown (isShutdown always false), no matter client or server, the main thread blocked.

#### Steps to reproduce

The code as follow.

#### Minimal yet complete reproducer code (or URL to code)

[The code in this issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7694)

#### Netty version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.20.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

#### JVM version (e.g. `java -version`)

java version "1.8.0_131"

#### OS version (e.g. `uname -a`)

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-104-generic x86_64)
- OSX 10.13.1

Answer (score 2):

It's the bug of the 4.1.20，just update to 4.1.21
[My issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7694)

The `clearThread` is not deamon thread

[image]